# how to create selectmenu "popup" Style with custom icon images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm very new to jquery, like 1 day old infant.
I have viewed this [jquery_ui_selectmenu](http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/), but I couldn't understand how to convert my select menu to the one in in that link that called "popup" Style with custom icon images.
This is my select code.

```
<select name="fromCurrency" id="fromCurrency">
    <option selected value="EUR">EUR</option>
    <option value="USD">USD</option>
    <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
</select>
```

### I basically want to create a popup/dropdown list with icons next to each option.

After trying to apply the changes as written below, the next code deosn't work.
What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EqU8X/1/)**

1. setup class attributes on your `<option>`s:

   ```
   <option selected value="EUR" class="eur">EUR</option>
   ```
2. setup the css for your icon using the `<option>`'s class then `.ui-selectmenu-item-icon`:

   ```
   .eur .ui-selectmenu-item-icon {background: url('your/icon/path') 0 0 no-repeat;}
   ```
3. finally configure the icons when you call `selectmenu`:

   ```
   $('#fromCurrency').selectmenu({
       icons: [
           {find: '.eur'},
           {find: '.usd'},
           {find: '.gbp'}
       ]
   });
   ```

Comment: I have tried to implement your example and jsfiddle example but without success. I run at on my easyphp server at my local machine and it didn't work. It just displayed a simple selectmenu, please look above, I have edited.

Comment: be sure to include the jquery-ui.css (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) and selectmenu.css (http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/ui.selectmenu.css)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you just need to include an array of objects specifying the class name that receives the icon and the path to the icon you'd like to use. Here's the demo provided by the website.

```
$('select#files, select#filesC').selectmenu({
    icons: [
        {find: '.script', icon: 'ui-icon-script'},
        {find: '.image', icon: 'ui-icon-image'} 
    ]

});
```